# why method setDrawerListener is deprecated?how to resolve it?

Tags: android, drawerlayout, deprecation-warning

In my android application I see the following error:

> setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.Drawer
>   Layout.DrawerListener)' is deprecated

How i can resolve this?

In one answer I see use `addDrawerListener()` instead `setDrawerListener` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: what is the problem you r facing? Please describe it then !!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of using `setDrawerListener()`, you could use `addDrawerListener()`.

> `public void setDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener listener)`
>   Sets a listener to be notified of drawer events.
>
> Note that this method is deprecated and you should use
>   `addDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)` to add a listener and
>   `removeDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)` to remove a
>   registered listener.

Comment: It's funny how you rip off from other's answers. Almost every single answer you've posted is basically copy+paste. At-least give the credit to the post you copied from.

Comment: Just tell me ..where it is written not to copy n paste.  I dint mark yes for my ans..so don't pin point.

Comment: Read this answer to the question here : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism. I believe in failure to give credit amounts to plagiarism. Considering almost every answer you've ever posted has been a copy,  I can flag you if I want but I wont. Please keep it in mind the next time you attempt to answer.
If you have found an answer somewhere, simply post a link in a comment.

Comment: Where? Right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 1):

Android official documentation states that setDrawerListener() should  be replaced by addDrawerListener() [setDrawerListener() Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerListener%28android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener%29)

So it should work as they both accept the same arguments.
You can read this also :[addDrawerListener Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#addDrawerListener%28android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener%29)

in case you're missing something or the logic of your code has flaws.

You can also paste some of your code if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Well aparently google added this new method after  API level 23.2.0.While both are same.Takes same arguments does same work... but in future it may not work somewhere i read.So its better to use

drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43535209/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.